# How to force abnormal termination of a bash script

Tags: bash, nas

I've a Synology NAS running DSM. I've created a bash script to check if a certain file is present within a certain folder. The script runs by a schedule and returns the result to me by email.

The problem is I get too many emails just saying the script ran ok.

The DSM task scheduler allows to send the email only if script terminates abnormally.

My question is: **how can I force the script to terminate abnormally?**

I would do so in order to get an email if the file I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `exit 1` to terminate the script.

Exit code `0` means everything went fine, all other indicate some kind of error.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an exit code if the file is missing:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/foo/bar"
if [ -e "$file" ]
then
exit 0
else
exit 1
fi
```

`[ -e ]` is an operator which checks if `"$file"` exists. It is equivalent to `test -e $file` but suited to if-else-fi.
See [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) if you need more operators.

Edit:
To further elaborate, there are also [other exit codes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) which you may use for convenience, assuming you have a different email warning for when the script 'blows up' or does not execute for some reason.